# Google Firestore - YouTube like view counter?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/solutions/counters

According to the above doc, you need to implement `distributed counter` for counters that are incrementing faster than `once per second`, which is pretty slow. 
With more number of shards, write throughput grows linearly, but it also states that the cost increases and read throughput decreases linearly.
So, how can you implement something like a YouTube view counter that is incrementing probably 1000 times a second without getting crazy high bills and extremely slow reads?
I don't think having a 1000 shards can be an efficient answer to this simple and common use case.

Comment: Youtube views are not realtime

Comment: You still have to count though.

Comment: What you can do is to use Firestore with the RTDB. When a user likes a post, you trigger a cloud function that will run a transaction to update a counter in the RTDB. I believe the RTDB has no problem to handles like thousand of operations per second and that's very fast. And then, you can set up a cloud scheduler to trigger a pubsub topic to grab the counter value and copy it into Firestore. So you end up with one write every... 30min ou 1 hour. Alright that's not real-time, but sometimes you have to deal with that.